# SOAP API - No operation available for request create

Tags: soap-api, soap, trailhead

I want to create an account using **SoapUI** as explained here:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_intermediate/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_soap

My request is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>

      <urn:AssignmentRuleHeader>
         <urn:assignmentRuleId>?</urn:assignmentRuleId>
         <urn:useDefaultRule>?</urn:useDefaultRule>
      </urn:AssignmentRuleHeader>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>xxxMYIDxxx</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:create>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <Name>Sample SOAP Account</Name>

         </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:create>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My endpoint is : https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/39.0.

What I get is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>No operation available for request {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}create</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I get it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that I should have deleted the

```
<urn:AssignmentRuleHeader>
```

So, the complete code should be:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <urn:SessionHeader>
      <urn:sessionId>00D0Y000001JXaR!ARgAQOPecVAq.xoTw251d4YEnviWYp5RL8JgCpvBCHlXUeik_M1ktn_aqAI9NecWNInaPgslo.teGXDknV4Ti92bAwz7mhy_</urn:sessionId>
    </urn:SessionHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:create>
      <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Name>Sample Inbound Account One</Name>
      </urn:sObjects>
    </urn:create>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are sending an enterprise WSDL request to the **Metadata API** https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/39.0 endpoint. Instead you should send to **Enterprise API** https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/39.0 endpoint.

Please refer to this Salesforce [KNOWLEDGE ARTICLE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000228430&language=en_US&type=1) for more details.

**'No operation available for request {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}' error when sending SOAP request**

**Description**

When I send a SOAP request from a third party application into salesforce, I receive the following error message

*No operation available for request {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}*

**Resolution**

This can occur when you are sending the request to the wrong endpoint. For example, depending on which WSDL you are using, the endpoint will be different, as follows

Partner WSDL: /services/Soap/u/34.0 
Enterprise WSDL: /services/Soap/c/34.0

Notice how the Partner WSDL has a 'u' in the path whereas the Enterprise WSDL has a 'c'. If you log in using the Enterprise WSDL and then use the Partner WSDL endpoint to make API calls, you will see this error. Make sure your API calls are sent to the correct endpoint, based on what WSDL you've chosen to use.